# nginx to server nested subdirectories

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

How should I speficy location directives to serve a static directory tree. 
Example: lets say if root = /var/www/publish, request : /publish/dir1/file1 
should fetch file1 from /var/www/publish/dir1/file and request of /publish/dir2/file2 should fetch /var/www/publish/dir2/file2 and there could be multiple such directories which is unknown and more nesting within a directory. How can I keep the conf simple so that I dont have to add separate location directives for individual subdirectories.

Comment: If you request is `/publish/whatever` then you should set root to `/var/www` and it will pervectly serve file `/var/www/publish/whatever`

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyTen, it was helpful. I was probably overthinking.